# RecyclerView Inconsistency on notify adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have the following piece of code:

```
for (child in children)
{
   items.add(book)
   viewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(items.count()-1)
}
```

This is the error that I obtain:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: edu.uoc.android.pac2, PID: 6949
>       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{c7d5aa8 position=10
>   id=-1, oldPos=1, pLpos:1 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent}
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{a74a62 VFED..... ......I.
>   0,0-1080,1536 #7f08002b app:id/book_recycler_view},
>   adapter:edu.uoc.android.pac2.SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter@9b0b7f3,
>   layout:android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager@13c8cb0,
>   context:edu.uoc.android.pac2.BookListActivity@23f070d
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5715)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5898)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LayoutState.next(LayoutState.java:100)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fill(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1609)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:683)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:605)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3875)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3639)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:625)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:753)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Only happens when I add items, the following code works:

```
items.clear()
viewAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size)
```

Also this:

```
val position = items.indexOf(elem)
items.remove(elem)
viewAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (child in children)
{
  items.add(book)
}
viewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(items.count()-1)
```

Please keep notifyItemInserted outside the loop and check it.

Comment: It's working. Isn't this supposed to be used with every item I enter in the list?

Comment: No, you dont have to do it every time you add an item to list. list is at once rendered by the recycler view rather than for each item in list.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of `notifyItemRangeInserted(startIndex, children.count())`?

Comment: As the name suggests for itself for a particular range in the list the data has been updated. You dont have to use it if you are changing the complete list itself.